# Splunk HEC sourcetype override mapping all events to a single transform

Tags: splunk, splunk-hec

I have got a Splunk instance running as an HEC in Docker. I want to implement sourcetype override on a per-event basis. For that, I've added the `props.conf` and `transforms.conf` files under the `$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local` directory.

Definitions for the files are as follows

`props.conf` is shown below

```
[source::*testing-token*]
ANNOTATE_PUNCT=false
TRANSFORMS-test_transform=test_transform_first,test_transform_second,test_transform_default
```

`transforms.conf` is shown below

```
[test_transform_first]
REGEX=\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}\]\s\[.*
DEST_KEY=MetaData:Sourcetype
FORMAT=sourcetype::mytestcustom:myservicelogs

[test_transform_second]
REGEX=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s.*
DEST_KEY=MetaData:Sourcetype
FORMAT=sourcetype::mytestcustom:accesscombined

[test_transform_default]
REGEX=.
DEST_KEY=MetaData:Sourcetype
FORMAT=sourcetype::mytestcustom:defaultevent
```

When I'm sending a raw event, the HEC maps it to the sourcetype of `test_transform_default` even though the event is a perfect match for either `test_transform_first` or `test_transform_second` transform.

Below is a screenshot for the same
[image]

To ensure that the regex is compliant on Splunk, I ran the below search query and got the expected result

```
index=testindex | regex "\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}\]\s\[.*"
```

The result is as below
[image]

The point worth noting is that the default transform is specified as the last transform in the `props.conf`

What's the possible cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The *first* time an event matches a `sourcetype`, it will fall into it

And if you *tag* an event with a given `sourcetype` in the actual HEC submission, it will *always* use that `sourcetype`

If you want something to come in differently, tag it differently in your HEC submission

Comment: You mean to say the regex `.` has highest priority and thus all results (without explicit `sourcetype`) will map to it?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy - I mean `sourcetype`. If you don't explicitly say what sourcetype something is, Splunk "guesses" it's the first one in the list (in my experience)

Comment: That's right. In the event of missing sourcetype, the Splunk documentation says that the way transforms are matched is in the way they are defined. So technically, I would expect the default to be executed last as it's in the last of the list `TRANSFORMS-test_transform=test_transform_first,test_transform_second,test_transform_default`. But that's what is not happening with events which match the `*first`/`*second` transform.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy - looks like you're getting a match in lexicographic order ("default" being lexicographically prior to "first" or "second"). Try renaming it to be lexicographically-*last* ... eg "`zzz-test_transform_default`"

Comment: Looks like the issue was with the Splunk instance. Performing a clean setup worked.